# Change the state of a class from a different class Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make the first floating action button be conditionally rendered based on if there is a true in the isPressed list. However, it is not rerendering as soon as it is changed and the button only shows up when I go back a screen and come back to it. How do I set the state to refresh everytime in the BreastFamilyChooser class when onPressed happens in the FamilyButtons Class?

```html
class BreastFamilyChooser extends StatefulWidget{

  BreastFamilyChooser({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  @override
  BreastFamilyChooserState createState() => new BreastFamilyChooserState();
}

class BreastFamilyChooserState extends State<BreastFamilyChooser> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[300],
          title: Text(
              "Family History with Cancer"
          )),
      floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: [
          router.isPressed.contains(true) ? Positioned(
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            child: Container(
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: null,
                elevation: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[800],
                child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next_rounded),
                onPressed: () async {

                },
              ),
            ),
          ) : Positioned(
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            child: Container(
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 60,
            bottom: 20,
            child: Container(
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: 20,
                elevation: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[800],
                child: Icon(Icons.navigate_before_rounded),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This is the class that changes the isPressed list. So would want to set the state of the class above so that router.isPressed.contains(true) evaluates to true when there is a true in the list right away.

```html
class FamilyButtons extends StatefulWidget{
  String person;
  int position;
  FamilyButtons({Key key, this.title, this.person, this.position}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  @override
  FamilyButtonsState createState() => new FamilyButtonsState();
}
class FamilyButtonsState extends State<FamilyButtons> {
  int _currentValue = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height  * 0.05,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                heroTag: widget.position,
                label: Text(
                  widget.person,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1000.0))),
                backgroundColor: router.isPressed[widget.position] ? Colors.indigo[600] : Colors.grey,
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _currentValue = 1;
                  router.isPressed[widget.position] = !router.isPressed[widget.position];
                  print(router.isPressed);
                }),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: (router.isPressed[widget.position]) ? NumberPicker.horizontal(
                    initialValue: _currentValue,
                    minValue: 1,
                    maxValue: 5,
                    onChanged: (newValue) =>
                        setState(() => _currentValue = newValue)
                ) : Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use state management for this problem. for example, you can use provider and set `listen=true` in your widget. you can see a step by step guide [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67966668/14636964)